# One function over div with same classes

Tags: jquery

How to use one jQuery function with many div's which shares one class. The function applied only for the first div. I have many img inside div's

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
    <div class="text" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Welcome to Winks</h2>
        <p>Watch the largest collection of Movies and TV series 
            anytime anywhere!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.text").fadeIn(3000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To clarify, is your desired behavior that it only be applied to the first div, or is this what's actually happening?

Comment: guess because I'm using carousel, all text displays simultaneosly. Therefore, on the next pic, text is diaplayed without fadeIn. I think loop is necessary here. But I dint know how to do it)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the inline style `style="display: none;"` on your `<div>`. Inline styles override almost anything in css (I believe anything that doesn't have !important), so they should be used very sparingly. It's very possible that this is overriding the `.fadeIn()`, which is probably using css in the background. If you moved the initial `display: none` to a css file, it could fix your issue.

Comment: I guess because I'm using carousel, all text displays simultaneosly. Therefore, on the next pic, text is diaplayed without fadeIn. I think loop is necessary here. But I dint know how to do it)

Comment: First of all, if you're using any outside libraries which could affect your solution, you should include them. Otherwise, how are people suppose to help you if they don't know the whole picture? Second of all, while I can't be certain because I don't know what "carousel" is, it's most likely just showing and hiding the elements as they come, meaning that they're always probably in the DOM and able to be acted upon.

Comment: Check in the dev console if all of the carasel items are indeed in the DOM. If they are, at least from the context you've given, your jQuery should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a space in between div and .text?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div .text").fadeIn(3000);
})
```

Demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/824L4e2k/1/

Comment: The OP's code has <div class="text">, so `div.text` is the correct CSS Selector.